# ocaml regex issue on "{{"

Tags: regex, ocaml

I am trying to match "{{" in a string:

```
let regexp = Str.regexp_string "{{"

let _ = if Str.string_match regexp "a{{hello}}" 0
    then print_string "yes"
    else print_string "no"
```

This prints "no".

Why is this not matching? "{" is not a special character: [$^.*+?[]](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html)

Unless I am reading the manual incorrectly, string_match is supposed to find any substring of s that satisfies the regexp.

Comment: Character `{` and `}` are special in almost all regex engines as far as I know, you should escape it with backslash

Comment: No, that is not it. I did try escaping. It is not a special character for ocaml's vanilla regex.

Comment: Not sure about this engine, maybe it tries to match hole string, try with something like `.*{{.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Str.search_forward` instead.

According to the [ocaml docs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html):

> string_match r s start tests whether a substring of s that starts at
>   position start matches the regular expression r.

I am guessing this means it doesn't traverse through the entire string like `search_forward` does.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [documentation](http://langref.org/ocaml/pattern-matching) the function `string_match` you are using tries to match the full string, so you should use:

```
let regexp = Str.regexp_string ".*{{.*"

let _ = if Str.string_match regexp "a{{hello}}" 0
    then print_string "yes"
    else print_string "no"

#load "str.cma" ;;
```

> **string_match**: Check if a string matches a regular expression

However, I think you might find useful using `search_forward` which actually it searches for a pattern within your string

```
let re = Str.regexp "{{" in
try let _ = Str.search_forward re "a{{hello}}" 0 in
  print_string "ok"
with _ -> ()
```

> **search_forward**: Check if a string contains a match to a regular expression

Comment: string_match doesn't attempt to match the full string, it attempts to match a substring that starts at the position supplied as an argument.

Comment: @JamesBuck thanks for your comment, I wrote that to let OP knows to use that regex. However, I quoted the documentation to be more accurate.